# Why does Countdown Timer reset when pages are changed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a timer that I am resetting every 24 hours in my app. This timer is called in my home page
and I'm using [Countdown_Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/countdown_flutter) for it. However when I go to another page and come back to Home it restarts the timer and doesn't continue from the time it was left at.
Is there anything I can do so that this doesn't reset?
This is the code:

```
CountdownFormatted(
        duration: Duration(hours: 24),
        builder: (BuildContext ctx, String remaining) {
          return Text(remaining); 
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Decouple the timer from your widget tree. Every time the widget gets rebuilt, it will reset your timer. Move it to a completely separate class, the simplest being a singleton. (You will probably not be able to use the `countdown_flutter` package while doing this.)

Comment: That didn't work @Abion47, could you suggest something else?

Comment: Define "didn't work".

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution @Simran Aswani?